# Looking a value with rounding up step in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

given the below table :

[image: looking area]

In the fourth column look up value the value 880.

Now, I want Excel to return the value `1000` because it’s the lowest value in column 4, which happens to be higher than `880`.

I want to do this without macro, so a solution that it is not possible using functions would be appreciated.

Comment: Only need higher value? If yes, you can try this formula: **=MINIFS(INDIRECT(CHAR(64+H1)&":"&CHAR(64+H1)),INDIRECT(CHAR(64+H1)&":"&CHAR(64+H1)),H2)** https://ibb.co/3BP36WM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE as a SMALL(IF()) to return the smallest number that is equal to or larger than the desired number.

The INDEX(MATCH) returns the correct column to search:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,INDEX(A:F,0,MATCH(I2,A1:F1,0))/(INDEX(A:F,0,MATCH(I2,A1:F1,0))>=I3),1)
```

[image]